# GraphicsDeviceManager

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, refactoring

Can anyone please help. Im following a tutorial on drawing primitives from the MSDN found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203926%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx).

I am trying to re-factor the code a small bit and to that end I have created a class called MyPrimitives in which I have placed all of the code from the tutorial. Then from e.g. Game11 Initialize() I can just call myPrimitive.Initialize() etc.

But I get a NullReferenceException at this line of code in MyPrimitives CreateVertexBuffer() method:

```
vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(
            graphics.GraphicsDevice,
            vertexDeclaration,
            number_of_vertices,
            BufferUsage.None
            );
```

And CreateVertexBuffer() is called from MyPrimitives Initialize() method like so:

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        CreateVertexBuffer();
    }
```

And THIS Initialize() is called from Game1 Initialize() like so:

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        myPrimitiveDrawer = new MyPrimitiveDrawer();

        myPrimitiveDrawer.Initialize();

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

I know the problem is cause I have not set my graphis [GraphicsDeviceManager graphics] to an instance of an object, but how do I actually do this?
I have tried:

```
public void Initialize()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);  // Tried this
        CreateVertexBuffer();
    }
```

But that just gives an error of invalid arguments.

Does anyone have any suggestion please?

Comment: does your class extend Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game?

Comment: Nope... So I should do public class MyPrimitives : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game? Will this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with your main game class and make it extend Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game

```
public class Game : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);  
            base.Initialize();
    }
}
```

Then you just need to make sure that all of your classes uses the same GraphicsDeviceManager when the project expand.